# How to fix the utf8 issue for CSV read process

Tags: perl, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have read and got the values from the CSV file. Sometimes I have faced the character encoding issue (uf8). Review my below sample code.

```
 my $value = 'Storno lt. Gläubiger';
 $value = encode( 'iso-8859-1', $value );
```

**Result return as**

```
Storno lt. Gl�ubiger
Storno lt. Gl\xE4ubiger
```

My expecting result is "Storno lt. Gläubiger"

How to fix the issue and get the expecting result.

Comment: Re "*I have read and got the values from the CSV file.*", Did you post the wrong code? It doesn't read from a CSV file. Please post code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is not complete. You did not provide minimal code snippet to understand what you try to do.

You need to take in consideration your output device (probably a screen) which should support `utf-8` output.

You did not provide any clue what OS (Operating System) you run the code in.

For example if you use Windows 10 (probably earlier version also will work) and try to get output into `cmd` terminal -- then before output you have to change **code page** to `utf-8` which can be achieved with `chcp 65001` command.

If you are in Windows then in `cmd` terminal window type `help chcp` and read some documentation.

If you write perl code and inside of the code you use `utf-8` strings then you need add `use utf8` in the beginning of your perl code.

[Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)